# Immediately resolve an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

From my `MainActivity` I'm calling a function that may or may not need to start another activity (a popup dialog) to return a result. In the case that it doesn't need to start another activity, how can I trigger `onActivityResult` without creating another window?

The use case is that, before performing certain activities, the user needs to have clicked an "I know what I'm doing." button at least 5 minutes before the app lets them do it. I'm trying to extract this into a function.

An analogy would be `Promise.resolve` in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know if you need `onActivityResult` if you're not starting the activity that returns the result?

Comment: Is there another channel through which to communicate a result back to the caller in a consistent manner, that may be used regardless of whether an activity was called?

Comment: If you need user input from the popup, but don't want to hassle the user every time, then you might save the value in `SharedPreferences` and check it from there

Comment: I don't want to persist the user output, I just don't need to ask for it every time.

Comment: You're going to need to persist that data if you want it to exist after any time the activity is destroyed - from phone calls, destroyed while in background or screen orientation changes

Comment: This has nothing to do with persisting data.

Comment: Then please feel free to describe your use case a bit better - because it looks like you're trying to return data from an activity that has never been started, or looking for a way to remember previously entered user data from that activity when it was once started.

Comment: Added the user case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160475/discussion-between-quadrupleslap-and-sqlitenoob).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want to follow here is to abstract your logic from onActivityResult(). In the below example, the activity wants to make sure that the user is signed in. The result handling logic is in handleSignInResult(). If the user is not signed in, then the activity for sign-in will be launched. If the user is signed in, then handleSignInResult() is called immediately.

```
private void init() {
    if(Foo.isSignedIn()) {
        this.handleSignInResult(true);
    } else {
        // TODO Launch the activity which will later cause onActivityResult() to be invoked
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // TODO Check intent data to determine how to call handleSignInResult()
    boolean success = true;
    this.handleSignInResult(success);
}

private void handleSignInResult(boolean isSignedIn) {
    // Do the stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have right now, but I was hoping Android would have a sensible abstraction over this, that didn't require this much boilerplate.

Comment: AFAIK Java does not yet have the built-in type of abstractions that you are asking for, such as C# Tasks or ES6 Promises.